# How to iterate through an array list on a JSP without JSTL

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, arraylist

//I have retrieved a Result from MySQL and created and Array-list User .i have sent this //US er Array-list in and sent it through request Response Object. Now i need to display iton //s JSP page.
//1.Without JSTL
//2.With JSTL

//The Name of table is user_reg it has four fields id,username,password,email.
//please do explain with example. i need to dispay all fields in a jsp page. but i dont want //to do the jdbc work on the JSP

```
 package kinder.dto;

    public class User {
        private String id;

    private String userName;
    private String saltedkey;
    private String emailId;
    private String legalName;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getLegalName() {
        return legalName;
    }
    public void setLegalName(String legalName) {
        this.legalName = legalName;
    }
    public String getEmailId() {
        return email;
    }enter code here`
    public void setEmailId(String emailId) {
        this.emailId = emailId;
    }
    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return saltedkey;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.saltedkey = password;
    }




    }


    //dto

     package kinder.dto;

    public class User {
        private String id;

    private String userName;
    private String saltedkey;
    private String emailId;
    private String legalName;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getLegalName() {
        return legalName;
    }
    public void setLegalName(String legalName) {
        this.legalName = legalName;
    }
    public String getEmailId() {
        return emailId;
    }
    public void setEmailId(String emailId) {
        this.emailId = emailId;
    }
    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return saltedkey;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.saltedkey = password;
    }

}
```

//servlet

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            List<User> users = UserDAO.list();
            request.setAttribute("users", users); // Will be available as ${products} in JSP
            request.getRequestDispatcher("loginSuccess.jsp").forward(request, response);
        } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new ServletException("Cannot obtain products from DB", e);
        }
    }
```

//how to get this in a JSP page

Comment: Why wouldn't you use the JSTL? Use it. And try something on your own. Google is your friend. If you try something and you're stuck, then come back here and post the code you tried.

Answer (score 3):

```
get some like this :

on jsp psge :

<% ArrayList<user> userList=(ArrayList<user>) request.getAttribute("user");
        Iterator<user> iter = userList.iterator();
        while(iter.hasNext()){

            user user = iter.next();
```

using pojo class access it :

user.getUsername();
user.getPassword();

```
    %>
```

Answer (score 1):

### With JSTL

You need to create POJO class

```
class UserReg {
  private Integer id;
  private String userName;
  private String password;
  private String email;
  //getters and setters
}
```

#### Servlet

Need to change list population logic

```
//code.....
ResultSet rs = ...;

ArrayList<UserReg> usersList = new ArrayList<UserReg>();

while(rs.next()) {       
   //here create new object of UserReg for each row
   UserReg user = new UserReg();
   user.setId(rs.getInt(0));
   // do it for userName, password, email
   .....
   .....
   ....
   // last add to list
   usersList.add(user);
}  
//set list in request scope and forward request to JSP
request.setAttribute("usersList",usersList);
```

#### JSP

```
<c:forEach var="user" items="usersList">
   <c:out value="${user.id}" />
   <c:out value="${user.userName}" />
   <c:out value="${user.password}" />
   <c:out value="${user.email}" />
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Hello Aniket//// I get the JSTL syntax.. i want to do it with JSTL as an Expression in an JSP page by recieveing a arraylist in a server

Comment: how to write the same code in JSP as an expression and not as a Tag

Comment: how to write the same code in JSP as an expression and not as a JSTL Tag

Comment: @lehrer : Why do you want an expression? It is not recommended to use.

Comment: just trying to learn.Please do help/ i know JSTL is better but i want to just add java first then leter start JSTL

Answer (score 0):

```
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@page import="kinder.dto.User"%>
...
...
<%
ArrayList<User> users = (ArrayList<User>) request.getAttribute("users");

for (User : users) {
%>
    <div><%= user.getId() %></div>
<%
}
%>
```