# print complete rows in table which is passed from servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have one jsp page and one servlet, In servlet i want to fetch some rows from a particular table and pass them to jsp .I am able to retrieve in servlet and trying to pass them in jsp it is not getting displayed please anyone help me out here...

```
public class TimeDetail extends HttpServlet {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, java.io.IOException {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
        String eid = (String) session.getAttribute("eid");
        int count = 0;
        Connection con = ConnectionManager.getConnection();
        try {
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            Statement st1 = con.createStatement();
            String Query = "select date, intime, outtime, eid  from fulltime where eid='" + eid + "'";
            ArrayList Rows = new ArrayList();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(Query);
            List agentList = new ArrayList();

            while (rs.next()) {
                ArrayList row = new ArrayList();
                for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
                    row.add(rs.getString(i));
                }

                String n1 = rs.getString("date");
                String n2 = rs.getString("intime");
                String n3 = rs.getString("outtime");
                String n4 = rs.getString("eid");

                session.setAttribute("n1", n1);
                session.setAttribute("n2", n2);
                session.setAttribute("n3", n3);
                session.setAttribute("n4", n4);

                // response.sendRedirect("TimeDetail.jsp");
                Rows.add(row);

            }
            request.getSession().setAttribute("results", Rows);
            RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/TimeDetail.jsp");
            rd.forward(request, response);

        } catch (Throwable theException) {
            System.out.println(theException);
        }
    }
}
```

and here is jsp code

```
<tr><td>
    <table width="600" height="300"align=center cellspacing=0 border="0" 
        <caption><h2>List of users</h2></caption>
        <tr>
            <th>date</th>
            <th>intime</th>
            <th>outtime</th>
            <th>eid</th>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach var="user" items="${Rows.rows}">
            <tr>
                <td><c:out value="${user.date}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${user.intime}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${user.outtime}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${user.eid}" /></td>
            </tr>
      </c:forEach>
    </table>
   </div>
        </table><BR>
        </fieldset>
    </td></tr></table>
   </td></tr>
    </table>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: no sir actually the values i can see when i am printing for servlet console its printing and after that i am adding in list(i am not good in collection concept so may be some problem) and sending on jsp so jsp is not showing any error its just not printing the rows its showing only empty table with their header section..

Comment: anyone help me here....i have tried same problem with bean class also it is also not printing its returning i think address in that case please help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your for each loop should be like this ,

```
<c:forEach var="user" items="${results}">
            <tr>
                <td><c:out value="${user}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${user}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${user}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${user}" /></td>
            </tr>
      </c:forEach>
```

And your servlet as ,

```
     try {
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            Statement st1 = con.createStatement();
            String Query = "select date, intime, outtime, eid  from fulltime where eid='" + eid + "'";
            ArrayList row = new ArrayList();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(Query);


     while (rs.next()) { 
                     row.add(rs.getString("date"));
                     row.add(rs.getString("intime"));
                     row.add(rs.getString("outtime"));
                     row.add(rs.getString("eid"));
    }
}
request.getSession().setAttribute("results", row);
            RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/TimeDetail.jsp");
            rd.forward(request, response);
```

Hope this helps !!

Comment: sir i have tried but its not working its showing empty please check my servlet coding once...

Comment: Your servlet code looks clumsy . to access like this `"${user.date}"` you need to set the value in the java pojo classes. try `"${user}"` alone

Comment: in jsp page for retrieving do i have to put the session to retrieve? if i have to put den i am confuse because i know passing normal session but this values are in loop and holding in Rows so how to put session for this...i mean syntax.... may be this is the problem..

Comment: it has no relation with java beans , will rewrite your servlet to pass the list as an update in my answer

Comment: see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21900810/how-to-iterate-through-an-array-list-on-a-jsp-without-jstl) it is the proper way you should follow

Comment: the answer which you have solved here...its not working tell me one thing what is that var="user"....is user any class?

Comment: see [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_foreach_tag.htm) to know about all `for:each` attributes

Comment: it will work . Any errors or still getting the same empty page ?

Comment: acording to that link i understand that user is here pojo class rite sir?

Comment: sir no not at all i have created two classes and m using alternatively both ways...one is bean concept and another is same this one servlet but no answer same response..

Comment: have you imported `jstl` taglib?

Comment: it is a temporary variable , used to iterate the for loop .

Comment: yea sir it was i thnk jstl problem only but now its printing 4 times i dont knwow why means one row is coming 4 times... on jsp page... the code you have provided here above that alone itself working..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51747/discussion-between-san-krish-and-sourav78611)

Comment: sir format is not getting proper if i am putting only one  <td><c:out value="${user}" /></td> then its printing in one column ... please help me to fix the format...

Comment: join the chat . we will continue in that